# How to create new pandas dataframe column from file that contains json?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with metadata about voice calls

It looks like

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   phone        100 non-null    string
 1   group_id     100 non-null    int64 
 2   question_id  100 non-null    int64 
 3   result       100 non-null    bool
```

I want to create column #4 that will contain some dialogue statistics, e.g. `total_words (int64)`, and data must be taken from exteral json file, containing speech-to-text recognition results

**Is there any build-in pandas way to do that ?**

I've tested with [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) but getting module errors (`ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` and `TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable`)

I'm looking for something like

```
df['total_words'] = pd.read_json('file://localhost:8888/auido/' + df['phone'] + '.mp3.wstat.json')
```

I would be glad if someone will provide a working code example of solving similar issue

UPD: output of json file is like `{"total_words": 74}`

Comment: Could you please share the output of json file, as we can read the json file content in different dataframe and perform join to the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['total_words']=df['phone'].apply(lambda x: pd.read_json(f'auido/{x}.mp3.wstat.json'))
```

Now each cell of `total_words` column contains another dataframe, you can access it using:

```
#for first row
df.iloc[0]["total_words"].head()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Your example looks clean. But in my Jupiter I get `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/auido/358411590810.mp3.wstat.json'>` error. Docs tell that `path_or_buf` param for local file in pandas.read_json (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) could be like `file://localhost/path/to/table.json` but it doesn't work in my case. Could you suppose why?

Comment: @PaulSerikov, I updated the answer. I assume the problem is a path. Please use `relative path`. In the updated answer I assumed `auido` directory is located in the same directory as the Jupiter script.